# C# Multiply textboxes answer always 1

Tags: c#, textbox, integer, double, multiplication

I have a problem with the following code.

```
bool TextBox2INT = true;
bool TextBox1INT = true;

int outputValue = 0;
int ButtonFind;

int TextBox1INT2 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1INT);
int TextBox2INT2 = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2INT);

TextBox2INT = int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out outputValue);
TextBox1INT = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out outputValue);

ButtonFind = (int)Math.Round((double)(TextBoxt1INT2 * 0.0333m * TextBox2INT2) + (double)(TextBox1INT2));
textBoxFind.Text = ButtonFind.ToString();
```

The problem is that the code works perfectly fine but when im debugging the answer in textBoxFind.Text is always 1.

Comment: Have you tried actually debugging your code? For example, looking at the values of the subexpressions?

Comment: The initialization of `outputValue` to zero isn't necessary since it's used as an out parameter (in the `TryParse` calls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `Convert.ToInt32(bool)` which will only ever give 0 or 1.

I think you meant:

```
int TextBox1INT2, TextBox2Int2;

bool textBox1Valid = int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out TextBox1INT2);
bool textBox2Valid = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out TextBox2INT2);
```

You should also take action if `int.TryParse` returns false - for example, telling the user to enter a valid number, instead of performing the calculation anyway. I'd also change your variable names, so you'd have something like:

```
int parsedTextBox1, parsedTextBox2;

bool textBox1Valid = int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out parsedTextBox1);
bool textBox2Valid = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out parsedTextBox2);

if (!textBox1Valid || !textBox2Valid)
{
    // Do something to warn the user here, e.g. a message box
    return;
}

double result = (parsedTextBox1 * 0.0333m * parsedTextBox2) + parsedTextBox1;
textBoxFind.Text = ((int) Math.Round(result)).ToString();
```

Comment: Picking up rep like shooting fish in a barrel there Jon! But you did go the extra mile with lots of helpful info, so +1 from me ;-)

Comment: @Dommer: Not unless the answer's accepted, to be honest. Getting *votes* is easy - getting *rep* isn't always :)